# Equal Height Boxes Using Flexbox (Not Working)

Tags: css

I'm trying to have a series of with equal height, but my code isn't working. I've read that this should be solved simply by adding "display: flex" to the child element(s), but I already have that and it's not working. I thought by adding "height: 100%" to the children would resolve the issue, but that doesn't help either.

```css
.card-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.card {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.card> :last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.card>* {
  margin: 0;
}

.card-header {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  padding: 120px 30px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center 15%;
}

.card-header.img1 {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/350");
}

.card-header.img2 {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/350");
}

.card-header.img3 {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/350");
}

.card-body {
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.icon {
  max-width: 32px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header img1"></div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h3>Header</h3>
      <p>Content</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/32" class="icon">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header img2"></div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h3>Header</h3>
      <p>Content</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/32" class="icon">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header img3"></div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h3>Header</h3>
      <p>Content</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/32" class="icon">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that your `.card` needs to have `align-self: stretch` in order to "stretch" across the cross-axis of the `.card-containers` flex.

There were a couple other things I noticed in your code though. First of all, your `.card-footer` is inside your `.card-body`. This will create difficulties for you. Also, you're using a lot of relative positioning, which (imo) is more difficult than using a flex container inside another flex container. Here's a CodePen with what (afaik) you're trying to do. Feel free to use it, or not use it.

https://codepen.io/AugustZellmer/pen/OJbKPxO

**Original, incorrect answer:**

I *think* that the problem is with the line `flex: 0 1 100%;` in the card. This line tells the card ~~

a) never get any bigger to fill the space

b) do shink to fit the space

c) try to be 100% (of something; of what depends).

Because I don't have you app handy, try replacing this line with `flex: 1 1 100%` (or maybe it's `flex: 1 1 200px`), and let me know if that works.

Comment: Yeah, that works, but had to take out "align-self: center." However, this leaves me with a new problem: "pinning" the last element within each box to the bottom relative to all the box sizes...

Comment: On .card I edited to be "flex 1 1 100%" which by itself didn't work, but then it did when I removed "align-self: center"

Comment: so, I've realized that I've misread your question. and I'm not sure the change I suggested is actually helping you.

Comment: If you were able to copy the relevant section of HTML/CSS into a CodePen that you could share, that'd make it a lot easier for me (and others) to help you.

https://codepen.io/

Comment: The equal height thing is solved... now I'm onto a whole other issue with the footer. Not sure if I should make a separate post about it though.

https://codepen.io/devin1229/pen/oNYKNar

Comment: There were a couple things in your code that were not ideal. It took me a minute to work through it, but here is what (afaik) you're trying to do.
https://codepen.io/AugustZellmer/pen/OJbKPxO